# Complicated utility function

Tags: microeconomics, utility

I am trying to answer this past paper question on microeconomics and a rather complicated utility function question. The question is below as well as my answer.

In my answer, I use the fact that the marginal rate of technical substitution (MRS) is equal to their price ratio. I think that I derive both demand functions for pizza and apple. I am not sure if they are right and I don't know how to answer:

**How James responds to an increase in the price of Pizza?**

Just looking at the price of pizza (p1) in the demand functions would mean that an increase in p1 would result in a decrease in demand for apples.

I feel like I have done something wrong and that I would have to consider substitution and/or income effects? I'm terribly confused.

[image: question]

[image: My answer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demand functions you have derived are correct.

The Marshall demands are given as

$$ x^\star(p_x,p_y,M) = \sqrt{\frac{M}{p_y}} \\[8pt]
y^\star(p_x,p_y,M)  = \frac{M - p_x \sqrt{\frac{M}{p_y}}}{p_y},$$

where $M$ is income and $p_x$ is pizza price and $p_y$ is the apple price.

To answer the question of how the agent responds to change in pizza price it would be standard to find derivatives and/or elasticities of demand with respect to the price $p_x$ for pizza.

The derivative of pizza demand with respect to own-price is given as
$$ \frac{\partial x^\star(p_x,p_y,M)} {\partial p_x} = 0, $$
which implies that the elasticity is

$$El_{p_x}x^\star(p_x,p_y,M) = \frac{p_x}{x^\star(p_x,p_y,M)}\frac{\partial x^\star(p_x,p_y,M)} {\partial p_x}  = 0,$$

so you can conclude that demand is perfectly inelastic. When the price increase the consumer simply keeps demand constant and substitutes away from apples. This is manifest from the fact that

$$ \frac{\partial y^\star(p_x,p_y,M)} {\partial p_x} = - \sqrt{\frac{M}{p_y^3}}, $$

which is clearly negative and by implication the cross-price elasticity $El_{p_x}y^\star(p_x,p_y,M) <0$.

This is "unusual" if you expected apples and pizza's to be substitutes with the demand of one increasing when the cross-price increase.

Comment: Thank you Jesper, I like the way that you applied the reasoning to show that it will only substitute away from apples and showed the quantity changes with changes in price of pizza px